# Ionic - textfield view scroll

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem. View scroll to bottom when I tapped input or textarea. Video is [here](https://youtu.be/N0ixqR6sOKQ)

**Code**

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
   <div class="item item-input" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; width: 95%; text-align: left;">
      <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Konu yazınız..." ng-model="todo.tktx"></textarea>
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

How can i fix this problem. Please help me!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Probably this is an issue; see https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-wrong-scroll-behavior-with-subheader-and-keyboard/42547

Comment: Yes this is my issue but not solved yet. Have your any idea about this issue?